# Android file upload to Amazon S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I want to upload images to my s3 bucket. I tried different solution to upload file such as [this tutorial](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-application-integrate-to-amazon-s3-tutorial) but I always get error as ssl exception :

> Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x55a53d5240: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

I found one comment about this exception Comment is if your network bad you can get on error. But my network is good.

My code is below:

```
private void uploadImage() {

    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getContext().getApplicationContext(),
            "us-west-2:************", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_WEST_2 // Region
    );


    ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration();
    configuration.setConnectionTimeout(50000);
    configuration.setSocketTimeout(300000);

    final AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider, configuration);

    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getContext().getApplicationContext());

    LocalImage image = mAddImageAdapter.getLocalImage(0);
    final File mFile = new File(image.getImagePath());
    long len = mFile.length();

    transferUtility.upload("2y1s-images", mFile.getName(), mFile).setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

            Log.i(TAG, "image upload state: " + state.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {


            Log.e(TAG, "image upload percentage: " + bytesCurrent + " -" + bytesTotal);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

            Log.e(TAG, "image upload error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: just checking - did you remember to add internet permision in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have internet,read and write permission

Comment: which version of the aws sdk are you using? (the latest?)

Answer (score 0):

I found exception reason after spent 2 days. Main reason of ssl exception is my cognito credential and s3 bucket at different region. I hope this answer help other peoples.